# get current socially logged in account django

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am using multiple `social authentication`s like google, likedin,github etc my `django` web app.How can i check which is the current logged in social account? is there any direct methods like `request.user.get_currentsocialaccount()`

Comment: Here it is checking wheather user socialy logged in or not. I need to know which social account currently user in?